# SharedPreference does not read local data in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In a Flutter project, on clicking the "SignUp" button, I need 2 things,

1. Saving data to cloud
2. Saving data to local storage.

I user SharedPreferece to save the data and to retrieve it. The problem is, the data I saved into local storage is available immediately after I Sign Up, but if I hot reload the emulator, the data shows null!

The function by which I saved the data to both cloud and local storage:

```
Future <void> _saveDataToFirestore(User? currentUser) async{
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("sellers").doc(currentUser!.uid).set({
  "sellerUID": currentUser.uid,
  "sellerName": _fullNameController.text.trim(),
  "sellerAvatarUrl": sellerImageUrl,
  "sellerEmail": currentUser.email,
  "phone": _phoneNumberController.text.trim(),
  "address": completeAddress,
  "status": "approved",
  "earnings": 0.0,
  "lat": position!.latitude,
  "lng": position!.longitude
});

// save 3 data locally
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await sharedPreferences.setString("uid", currentUser.uid);
await sharedPreferences.setString("email", currentUser.email.toString()); // do not take from controllers, because it will not be null if sign up fail
await sharedPreferences.setString("name", _fullNameController.text);
await sharedPreferences.setString("image", sellerImageUrl);

print("${currentUser.uid},${currentUser.email.toString()}, ${_fullNameController.text}, ${sellerImageUrl} ");}
```

I initialized `SharedPreference` in `main.dart`

```
    Future <void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

The `home_screen` where I needed the local storage data

```
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_fancy_chef/authentication/auth_screen.dart';
import 'package:food_fancy_chef/authentication/login.dart';
import 'package:food_fancy_chef/authentication/register.dart';
import 'package:food_fancy_chef/global/global.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = "home_screen";

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}


class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String sharedName = "Null value";

  Future<void> _getIntFromSharedPref()async{
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final startupName = pref.getString("name");
    if(startupName == null){
      sharedName = "no name";
    } else{
      setState(() {
        sharedName = startupName;
      });

    }

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getIntFromSharedPref();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _getIntFromSharedPref();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Colors.cyan,
                    Colors.amber
                  ],
                  begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                  end: FractionalOffset(1.0, 1.6),
                  stops: [0.0,1.0],
                  tileMode: TileMode.mirror
              )
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(
          sharedName // I need "name" from local storage
          //   sharedPreferences!.getString("name")! == null? "null value":sharedPreferences!.getString("name")!
        )
      ), 
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  firebaseAuth.signOut();
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> LoginScreen()));
                });

              },
              child: Text("Log Out"),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  firebaseAuth.signOut();
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> AuthScreen()));
                });

              },
              child: Text("signout"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I have tried:

1. I have tried to get the data directly without any `init()` method, it returns null:

   ```
   sharedPreferences!.getString("name")! == null? "null value":sharedPreferences!.getString("name")!
   ```
2. I have declared the variable first and assigned the value via a function run at `init()`, code is below.
3. I tried the same process above but with `didChangeDependencies()` method.
4. I used both `init()` and `didChangeDependencies()`
5. I deleted the emulator and reinstalled it.

I also saved `SharePreferences()` in a `global.dart` file, so that, I can access them anywhere in the project.

[image: before and after "Restarting emulator "]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Future<void> _getIntFromSharedPref() async{
    SharedPreferences? pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String startupName = pref!.getString("name") ?? 'no name';
    setState(() {});
    }
```

Comment: it says "The '!' will have no effect because the receiver can't be null. (Documentation)  Try removing the '!' operator."

and throw error ` :: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SharedPreferences' which excludes null.
 - 'SharedPreferences' is from 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart' ('../../AppDev/flutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-2.0.12/lib/shared_preferences.dart').
    final startupName = pref!.getString("name")?? "no name";`

Comment: Edited code. Try again.

Comment: Hello Varun! I tried the edited code, Its same as before. The null check (!) operator cause the error. 
log: `Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SharedPreferences' which excludes null.
 - 'SharedPreferences' is from 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart' ('../../AppDev/flutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-2.0.12/lib/shared_preferences.dart').
     String startupName = pref!.getString("name") ?? 'no name';`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});` from main.dart.

Comment: Still same result. @Pranav

Comment: @Mafruh I tried recreating the problem and this line seemed to be the one resulting in null value. I would suggest to remove this line even for different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When `hot restart` the widget tree re built it means only this
`Widget build(BuildContext context)` method triggered. `initState` is called only once for a widget and `didChangeDependencies` may be called multiple times per widget lifecycle. So initializing some thing on `didChangeDependencies` you have to be careful. Calling like this will resolve your issue `whille hot restart`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
_getIntFromSharedPref();
return Scaffold(
   );
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Saddan! Tried replacing the `_getIntFromSharedPref()` inside Widget build. Problem still persists.